# python: while loop not checking the condition

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
l=raw_input()
x=l.split(' ')
n=x[0]
w=x[1]
l=raw_input()
i=0
print n
while(i<n):
    print "1 %d" %i
    i=i+1
```

and for input like

```
6 6
1 2 3 4 5 3
```

Its giving a run time error.

Though `n` is assigned 6 and `i` is started from 0, why is not getting end at when i=6? Value of `i` is increasing for more than `n` till infinite.

Comment: `n` and `w` are strings. Convert them to integers using `int` and most likely it'll be fine.

Comment: You have to keep in mind, that in Python, everything's an object.  So a string is not just an array of characters, it's an object.  Python is also strongly typed, so you (usually) have to typecast everything in order to have it treated as the desired object type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`n` is a string; `raw_input()` returns strings and you split that on spaces. `i` is an integer. Python doesn't coerce strings to integers when comparing, and always sorts numbers before strings, so `i<n` is *always* True:

```
>>> 6 < '6'
True
```

Convert `n` to an integer:

```
n = int(x[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> print n
6
>>> type(n)
<type 'str'>
>>> print 1 < n
True
>>> print 100 < n
True
```

`n` is a string and should not be compared to a number.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that the `split()` function returns a **string**, and in your condition

```
while(i < n):
```

you are comparing a string with an integer. That comparison will always return `True`.

**How can you fix it?**

You can convert `n` into an integer:

```
n = int(x[0])
```

**Note:** Also, remember that `raw_input()` will return a string.

Comment: Maybe a typo, but that comparison (`int < string`) will *always* return `True`

Comment: @TyrantWave edited. Thanks, non-native English speaker :)